# Spring Security Using X.509 Authentication and Periodically Updating Authorization UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, cxf, x509

I used Spring and Apache CXF to create a REST webservices application.  I'm using x.509 certificates to authenticate the users, and then a custom authorization service to get all of the user groups and details.  I've implemented a custom *UserDetailsService* that extracts the user information and populates a *UserDetails* object.  Part of the process of populating this object involves a request to the corporate authorization service.  The authorization service is unfortunately a proprietary system, but at least they provide a Java API.  The authorization service, among other things, returns a list of groups that the user belongs to.

I'm still in the development stage, but my observations so far seem to indicate that the *UserDetailsService* is called once upon initial connection.  Then each request uses a cached authorization object.

So my question and potential problem are this... Corporate policy states that applications are only allowed to cache the users authorization details for a set period of time.  So, how long does Spring keep these *UserDetails* objects cached before refreshing them?  And, how can I control this cache time to make sure I comply with policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a ticket submitted for something similar to this request:

- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-898

The advice in the ticket is to create your own filter than periodically sets the Authentication.setAuthenticated property to false, forcing a look up of the user. You might be able to achieve the same by setting a smaller session timeout

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I modified my implementation of _UserDetailsService_ to use _EhCacheBasedUserCache_ and set the TTL property to the appropriate expiration value.  That takes care of one part of the problem, where the authorization service no longer has to be consulted as often.  I'd also like to implement a filter, as mentioned in the post, to periodically check user sessions and expire them if needed.  Any tips on where to start?  I've never created a custom filter before.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the other part of the problem based on the answer to another post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10322026/1354698