# Set property of FilterSecurityInterceptor without creating custom filter

Tags: spring-security

If I understand correctly, when I configured Spring Security an instance of *FilterSecurityInterceptor* was created automatically.  I would like to set the *alwaysReauthenticate* property to **true**, but I don't want to create my own *FilterSecurityInterceptor* or configure my own custom filter chain.  Is there a way to do this?

*Update: May 01, 2012*
Based on the comment below I came up with this code, which is working just as desired:

```java
public class ForceAuthCheckinator implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (beanName.contains("FilterSecurityInterceptor")) {
            ((FilterSecurityInterceptor) bean).setAlwaysReauthenticate(true);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Then in my *application context* file I added this single line, which activated the class and wired it into place:

```xml
<bean class="com.mydomain.ForceAuthCheckinator"/>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical solution for this kind of problems is to create a [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that will intercept initialization of `FilterSecurityInterceptor` bean and apply necessary customizations to it.